# Why are obstacles added at the edges of the global costmap when GlobalPlanner is used?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap, global-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently run into the following problem. It looks like while using `global_planner/GlobalPlanner` as global planner whenever I give a goal, obstacles in form of lines are formed at the edges of the global costmap. Since I am using `rolling_window: true`, the line-shape obstacles are created when the costmaps move together with the robot.

This is a weird issue since the planner shouldn't be creating obstacles at all at any point. I could not reproduce this problem using different global planner (like `carrot`, `navfn`) and is not connected to the local planner as well (tried out `eband`, `pose_follower` and `base_local_planner`). I also tried disabling all costmap related plugins except the `obstacles_layer` but the lines are still created when the `global_planner` is used.

My initial guess is that there is something wrong with the costmap update when the costmap moves for one resolution step but I cannot understand how is this connected with the `global_planner`? Maybe it somehow messes with the costmap update so whenever the costmap moves the new values are updated with lethal cost or it is connected with my costmap configuration files (which I doubt since it works fine with other planners). I also tried tinkering with the global costmap update/publish frequency and resolution but the obstacles still appear. Changing the update/publish frequency though clears the obstacles but does not stop the creation of new ones.

Has anyone run into this problem? You can see the obstacles on the image and the  bellow:
[image: image description]

EDIT:
Also tried it with [jackal_navigation](https://github.com/jackal/jackal) and the same problem still occurs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334103/why-are-obstacles-added-at-the-edges-of-the-global-costmap-when-globalplanner-is-used?/) by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1655 on 2019-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`global_planner` does not do bounds checking. Instead it [outlines the entire map](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/global_planner/src/planner_core.cpp#L287) with lethal obstacles so that it will never hit the edge case. It was not intended for use with `rolling_window`

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-10-01**:
Thanks for the information. I found that an existing [issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/907) regarding this already exists. As suggested by you I will make a PR with a parameter that enables `outlineMap`.